# ¿Como consultar datos desde dos colecciones de firebase desde flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Soy muy principiante en el manejo de flutter y firebase.
Pero mi duda es la siguiente:
Es una app de finanzas, tengos 2 colecciones en firebase una de gastos y otra de ingresos, para poder mostrar al usuario el balanca general de gastos y ingresos, necesito obtener el total de cada uno.
Logre obtener el total del valor de gastos mediante un map, pero no se como obtener ahora el de ingresos.
Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar

Comment: Creo que tambien se puede hacer con un future, pero no tengo la menor idea de como

Comment: Buenas, Josseline y bienvenido a SO. Lamento decirte que este tipo de preguntas no cumplen el formato adecuado. Una pregunta debe ser concisa y concreta; enfocada en una sola cosa y, además, presentar siempre el código que se ha intentado. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta y añadir el código de lo que llevas hasta ahora. Y si no has intentado nada, entonces te recomiendo hacer búsquedas por google e intentarlo primero. Saludos.